# Target ResolveReferences is not found

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I am trying to publish an ASP.Net website through NAnt/MSBuild calls.  MSBuild is called using the following arguments:

```
<arg value="SubsManager.sln" />
<arg value="/t:ResolveReferences" />
<arg value="/t:_CopyWebApplication" />
<arg value="/p:Configuration=Release" />
<arg value="/p:OutDir=..\builda\Release\Web\bin\" />
<arg value="/p:WebProjectOutputDir=..\Publish\" />
<arg value="/logger:C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll" />
<arg value="/verbosity:detailed" />
```

When I try the build under cruise control I get the following error:

> error MSB4057: The target "ResolveReferences" does not exist in the project.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ? I have  warning : The referenced project 'xxx.csproj' does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

MSBuild Deployment task needs a project (and not a solution) to run.........

Answer (score 0):

you could just remove the command to

`<arg value="/t:ResolveReferences" />
 <arg value="/t:_CopyWebApplication" />`

This would stop it from being called. The .SLN file already has all the references, build order information it needs to build the file with correct dependencies.